# Axios as library parameter in config file

Tags: axios, swagger-codegen

Is there `any need of/or any support` for Axios as library parameter in config file while generating client stub using swagger-codegen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VueJs and Axios, there is a swagger-codegen for that:
https://github.com/chenweiqun/swagger-vue

Just run in update api-docs url and run in node.